# Python flask application running on nohup python app,py & command in server is stopped running in linux redhat server

Tags: python, linux, flask

I have a python flask application which is stopped working in linux redhat 7.9 server after restart it is working fine and after some time we can't able to access again, the error message is site can't be reached at the moment.

but when i open and see the Linux server again. process is still running for the application, but can't be reached, memory and ram seems not an issue.

and there is no error logs in the application as well.

After we kill a zombie process after 2 days running on different port, after that it seems working fine the issue not replicated. does the zombie process is the root cause of the issue or any other possible issue might be there, please suggest.

We killed zombie process.

I'm expecting the root cause of the issue, i'm not sure whether the zombie process is the root cause